# How can I get permanent access to files in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am working in app that tells the count of folders and files exist on Desktop in macOS, for making things easier to my issue get solved I made a simple and small project that re create the problem. At first time of lunching the app I am asking the user to select the Desktop, after I am using the selected path for later use case when the app get killed, I do not want ask user each time to select the Desktop each time, it would be very bothering! currently sometimes macOS allows my app to get access to Desktop without showing the permission dialog but sometimes it goes ask each single time, I am trying to make my app authorized for such permission via user and use that permission for later use case in app. For example as you can see Terminal has such permission in the picture:

[image]

So here is my code with disabling sandbox:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var contents: [String]? = nil
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            Text("Count of contents of Desktop is:")
            Text(contents != nil ? String(contents!.count) : "Unknown").bold()
        }
        .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            contents = directoryContentsReader(folderLocation: "/Users/myNameHere/Desktop")
        }
    }
    
}

func directoryContentsReader(folderLocation: String) -> [String]? {
    do {
        return try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: folderLocation)
    }
    catch(let error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

And as said before most of the time and randomly I get this below dialog from macOS, I want make this kind permission done one time and for ever when the user use my app, and not bothering user with this dialog any more. How can I get this permission for my app?

[image]

Comment: "I want make this kind permission done one time and for ever when the user use my app, and not bothering user with this dialog any more." You are sandboxed. Either you need to keep a security scoped bookmark or you need the user to grant you permission in Preferences (as in your screenshot).

Comment: I would invite you to read the docs. For instance, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference/asset/media-rep/bookmark/enabling_security-scoped_bookmark_and_url_access

Comment: @matt: In my question and in my project I removed sandbox to make my app works even with that bothering dialog, I never worked on security scoped bookmark, do I need keep sandbox for security scoped bookmark or not? also do we need to hard code the path we need or we can dynamically set the wished path for  security scoped bookmark?

Comment: If you're seeing the dialog in the screenshot, you are still sandboxed.